# how to make unsortable header colmn in theme_table drupal 6

Tags: theming

I m using Drupal 6
I m using pager_query and theme_table
How can I make any column unsortable, by default it is making all columns sortable

```
$tableHeader = array(
        array('data' => ''),
        array('data' => 'Article','field' => 'a.title'),
        array('data' => 'From date','field' => ''),
        array('data' => 'To date','field' => ''),
        array('data' => 'Perpetual','field' => ''),
        array('data' => 'Access type ','field' => ''),

        );
```

here first column shows check boxes along each row so don't want this column sortable
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code for [`tablesort_header`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--tablesort.inc/function/tablesort_header/6) the sortable stuff is only added if the particular header item is an array. So you can cancel off certain columns by just setting the header to a string, e.g.:

```
$tableHeader = array(
  'This colum header is not sortable.',
  array('data' => 'Article','field' => 'a.title'),
  array('data' => 'From date','field' => ''),
  array('data' => 'To date','field' => ''),
  array('data' => 'Perpetual','field' => ''),
  array('data' => 'Access type ','field' => ''),
);
```